# Perl exclude words with pattern

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have Filename which contains a lot of strings, but I need to cut only specific names and exclude other garbage from the string

Example of File:

```
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jdfmfh_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jadxfh_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jdfmfh_value_javac10+.log
```

So I need to get result like:

```
component.jdfmfh
component.jadxfh
component
component
component.jdfmfh
```

I wrote small perl expression and got close result, but I don't know how to exclude all lines `_value_javac10+.log` from there.

```perl
perl -pe 's/^.*\/logs\///;' Filename
```

P.S. If there's a way to do it through the `sed`, that works for me as well

Comment: `perl -nE 'say $1 if (m|/logs/(component[^_]*)|)' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following solutions.

***1st solution:*** Using GNU `awk` and its `match` function which creates a capturing group into array arr and printing its first item as per requirement.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*\/([^_]*)_/,arr){print arr[1]}'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` here with regex to obtain the required output.

```
grep -oP '^.*\/\K[^_]*'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using field separator as `/` and splitting last field with `_` and printing very first element of array as per needed output.

```
awk -F'/' 'split($NF,arr,"_"){print arr[1]}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's:.*/logs/\([^_]*\).*:\1:' file
component.jdfmfh
component.jadxfh
component
component
component.jdfmfh
```

If you have any lines in your input that don't match that regexp and so you don't want printed then tweak it to:

```
sed -n 's:.*/logs/\([^_]*\).*:\1:p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last part as well, you will need to match all parts and only keep the desired part:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*logs\/([^_]*)_.*/$1/'
```

The part in () will be the one you sill want, outputted by $1.

Comment: Tip: Using an alt delim is clearer: `perl -pe's{^.*/logs/([^_]*).*}{$1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's~.*/\|_.*~~g' input_file
component.jdfmfh
component.jadxfh
component
component
component.jdfmfh
```

Comment: Elegant whittling!

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, the Perl solution for which you were aiming is

```bash
perl -pe's{^.*/logs/([^_]*).*}{$1}'
```

But you could also use

```bash
perl -ne'print $1 if m{/logs/([^_]*)}'
```

```bash
perl -ne'print $& if m{/logs/\K[^_]*}'
```

```bash
perl -nle'print for m{/logs/([^_]*)}g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jdfmfh_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jadxfh_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component_value_javac10+.log
FAILED, see /release/jenkins/workspace/Build/RELEASE/logs/component.jdfmfh_value_javac10+.log
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{sub(/_.*/,"",$NF);print $NF}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
component.jdfmfh
component.jadxfh
component
component
component.jdfmfh
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is slash, then for each line I do replace `_` and all following characters using empty string (i.e. delete them) in last field (`$NF`), then `print` said field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='.*/|_.*' OFS=
> ```

```
component.jdfmfh
component.jadxfh
component
component
component.jdfmfh
```